# How unique RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(int count) is?

Tags: java, uuid, uniqueidentifier

I need to generate a unique alphanumeric id, I could use UUID but the generated string is longer than I need, I would like a generated string of length 8 (more or less).
Therefore I thought of using RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(int count) of Apache lang.
I know there is no 100% guarantee that the string will be unique so I wonder if someone knows the probabilities of having duplicates when using e.g. count of 8 or 9?
Thanks.

Comment: get ths hashCode of the UUID

Comment: You could store the generated string somewhere and check against storage when generating in order to ensure unicity.

Answer (score 4):

Quickly looking at the javadoc it seems to pick chars from ascii letters and numbers only, so 36 characters. The probability to get a given string of 8 characters is therefore 36^8 ~ 3E12. For 9 characters the probability is 36^9 ~ 1E14.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I'm afraid it is a bit more complicated. Is there a distinguish between lower and upper case? On top of that I guess it depends on the how random is the algorithm used.

Answer (score 0):

It's as random as java.util.Random, in default impl. And it counts uppercase as different. Example return: BdODmKWjGtaKeFyYsNCbOPRzquNIIRMiEFPjqTSgbfMvMeZgNKihEdUdUXUniHUh

So your math is: 1/2.18340106e14.

If you need an unique ID in non-distributed system, you should perhaps opt for `AtomicInteger`, or some library for that purpose.